# webpack and TerserPlugin: compress is not turned on, but the output is one line

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

In webpack config, I use terser-webpack-plugin. I set the compress attribute false but the output is one line. The configuration is as follows

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      terserOptions: {
        compress: false,
        mangle: true
      }
    }
    )]
  }
}
```

I want the JS bundle multi-line no comments and mangle, how can I write the configuration of webpack?

the versions:

- "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.5"
- "webpack": "^4.39.1",
- node:v12.13.0

Answer (score 3):

I can only assert, that I cannot see how this works either. Maybe Webpack's minimize overrides the `compress` option from Terser?

You can get a multiline result though by "beautifying" the output:

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: true,
          output: {
            beautify: true
          }
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: thanks...the "beautifying" saved me. the compressed code on one line was leading to a very supper sluggish experience when I open this code on a certain product app online editor (which I had to) because of the endless horizontal scroll that chrome browser almost gave up on..